# How to replace the overflow icon with text button like "MORE"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to replace the standard three dot overflow icon with a text button like "More Pizza", so that users will see the option easily.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/file"
        android:title="main"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <!-- "file" submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/create_new"
                android:title="subitem1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/open"
                android:title="subitem2" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

In Activity
this below code is of `Kotlin`
don't worry if you using java, Android studio will do it for you. :)

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu)
        return true

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`app:showAsAction="always"` will display the title of the menu on the toolbar

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That would display one of the menu item with title. I want to show the the whole menu just like clicking the overflow icon